# zoom rubber band missing in IE11 with esri js api 3.10

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, internet-explorer

I am no longer seeing the rubber band in the browser when a user does a zoom operation where they can draw their zoom extent. This started breaking when i added in a X-UA tag = 'Edge'.
I am testing with IE11 but need to support IE10 as well.
The reason i had to change that X-UA tag was because some other thing was breaking in IE.

Anyone having issues with this zoom rubber band?
All of the esri samples now use the +/- zoom buttons and not the variable zoom so i can't even test one of those.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue identified where the zoom rectangle not appearing in IE10 and IE11. I could not find the discussion in GeoNet. From my recollection, this was apparently tied to the use of Dojo 1.9.x in the JS API from 3.7 to 3.10 (maybe earlier) and supposedly fixed in Dojo 1.10.0 with v 3.11 of the API. So try 3.11 to see if it fixes this for you.

With many of the sandbox examples (currently at 3.11), you can hold down the shift key while dragging the mouse to use the rubbber band zoom. With a tiled basemap, you will ultimately zoom to the closest zoom level but the rubber band does appear while dragging.

Comment: I am still seeing this issue with the Edge setting